# java.lang.NullPointerException: itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_movie) must not be null

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, nullpointerexception, null

I don't understand why this error is appearing that the itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_movie) cannot be empty. Where is it empty? can someone explain to me?

```
class MainViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bind(movies: Movie){
        val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_movie)
        image.setImageResource(movies.urlCoverImg)
    }
}
```

I could not understand. I've looked for an answer, but nothing in my case.

Comment: Your `itemView` doesn’t contain a view with that ID.

Comment: Use `view.findViewById()` instead of `itemView.findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.findViewById(R.id.img_movie)` instead of `itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_movie)`

You are trying to reference something in the out-of-bounds area of the recycler.